# How do I install md5deep in Git Bash (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, bash

How do I install md5deep in Git Bash as the `make` command is not working in Git Bash.

I tried with wget, apt-get and a few other methods.

Comment: Hello may i know for giving -1. If you feel it is very easy can I expect a solution for this please.

Comment: What is md5deep, what have you tried, which errors do you get? What is git bash, where was it obtained from? (Is it from git-for-windows, or a different setup...)

Answer (score 1):

Git Bash does not ship with GNU Make or package utilities. For that you would need Cygwin.

If you would like a more "official" means, try [Bash on Ubuntu for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which I find more streamlined and easier to use.

If you'd like the latter, Windows 10 is still free for Windows 7 users.